# Mac keyboard shortcut for "run last class" and "toggle breadcrumb"

Tags: eclipse, macos

1. Is there a keyboard shortcut for "run (last class)" in eclipse for Macbook pro? The icon for this is the running man in motion. I've searched for it but I can't find a keyboard shortcut.
2. I want my Project explorer to load from the left side like the original default setting. But I think I mistakenly messed it up somehow and the Project Explorer looks like it loads horizontally above the open classes. The Project Explorer horizontal bar appears and disappears whenever I press the "toggle breadcrumb" green button. I don't really know what "toggle Breadcrumb" has to do with the Project Explorer. How do i reset the location and appearance of default Project Explorer ?

Comment: Sounds like you are using a really old version of Eclipse.  What version are you using?

Comment: @whiskeyspider how do i check the version I'm using? Is it under preferences or properties? Ive check both places but can't find the version number.